# How can I convert a Vec<Option<T>> to an Option<Vec<T>>

Tags: rust

I have some vectors like this

```
let example1: Vec<Option<u64>> = vec![None, None, Some(2), Some(35)];
let example2: Vec<Option<u64>> = vec![Some(5), Some(19), Some(4), Some(6)];
```

and I want a function that would return `None` for `example1` but would return `Some([5, 19, 4, 6])` for `example2`.

In other words, I want a function that returns `None` if any of the options are `None`, but if all the options are `Some` it unwraps them all and returns `Some`.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Convert it into an iterator and use `.collect::<Option<Vec<_>>>()`.

```
let output = vec.into_iter().collect::<Option<Vec<_>>>();
```

or using type annotations

```
let output: Option<Vec<_>> = vec.into_iter().collect();
```

See [`collect()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.collect) and the [`FromIterator` trait implentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.FromIterator.html#method.from_iter-13) it uses for `Option`s.

Comment: Note that there is an implementation for Result too.